# My bot wont run the on_message/on_ready event properly

Tags: python, discord.py

When i tried to start up my bot, it wouldnt run the on_message event and it wouldnt run the on_ready event either.

Here is my code:

```
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ";", help_command = None)

dates = datetime.now()
date = datetime.today()
client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready")


client.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
    text = message.content
    print(author + " said at " + dates + " : " + text)
    client.process_commands(message)
```

I have tried to get rid of the on_message event to see if that was the problem, and it didnt fix it. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Do you run your bot with `client.run(token)` or did you removed it in your question ?

Comment: `client.process_commands` is a coroutine, you need to await it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually using the correct *decorators* for the `on_ready` and `on_message`. Any decorator should start with a @, notice how you are only using `client.event` instead of `@client.event`.

Also make sure to activate some intents for your bot or you will not be able to access some specific information.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ";", help_command = None, intents = intents)
```

Your corrected code should be something like this:

```
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ";", help_command = None, intents = intents)

dates = datetime.now()
date = datetime.today()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
    text = message.content
    print(author + " said at " + dates + " : " + text)
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting your bot with:

```py
client.run(insert your token in quotes here)
```

at the end of your file?

Comment: Yes i am. I only copied the relevant parts of my code. The bpt is online but it isnt running the events.